# difference between APIkit and APIkit Console components in mule?

Tags: mule

what is the difference between APIkit and APIkit console in mule?

as far as i know about APIkit is it helps us to reach our actual flow without creating manually as we configured required things in raml.

i have no idea about API kit console component.

could anyone help me understand the difference between APIkit and APIKit Console Components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes APIKit autogenerates your flows and routing based on your api spec. It generates the backend impl flows, error handling and status code mapping and more.

The router is for routing the HTTP request to the correct flow based on the method, path, uri Params etc. It introspects the raml and maps the request to the correct flow.(you can also provide manual mappings)

The apikit console is not mandatory. It provides an auto generated interactive HTML console for interacting with your api for testing etc. It is auto generated from your RAMl/api spec. It

In studio it will pop up as a view pane when you start the app containing the console flow and you can use the url you defined to access the console in a browser also.
Usually something like /api/v1/console
It’s the same type of console that is in Exchange and API designer for interacting with your api.